# How does Lord Shiva makes people realize of their wrong did?

Tags: shiva, gods

I know that kali and shiva make up the destroyers in Hinduism. From what I've heard, shiva makes people realize what they've done wrong. But the question is that do they punish you in order to teach you what you've done wrong. How do they cut away the bad in people, is it through life lessons? Do they make us realize by letting us experience bad situations? Do they bring out the bad karma to teach their devotees?

I'm sorry I don't know much about Hinduism.

Comment: Shiva, the supreme consciousness blindfolds himself and begins to play with himself through his power (Shakti) like Ikshya, Jnana and Kriya. So, it is Shiva himself who is in the form of enlightened beings as well as henious criminals. The difference is that enlightened has already removed their blindfold through grace (Anugraha) of Shiva while criminals (and others) are still in blindfold and they keep on tightening their blind fold by other dirts like Karma bandhan. So, for removal of this dirt he again and again takes birth and finally through Grace of Shiva knows himself as Shiva.

Comment: God does not punish us. We punish ourselves. To think of God as a punisher is a Judeo-Christian belief. We are the result of our own past karma, of the actions we do to ourselves. Good actions reap good karma. God is all love. He sees our actions as we see puppies fighting among themselves. In the end He knows it does us no harm, we all obtain God, no one is lost; some just take longer than others.

Comment: @ Swami Vishwananda 1: Thanks for the enlightment.  Wherever, there is a concept of rebirth in religious beliefs, in those religions, God is always benevolent, kind, forgiving and very rarely gets angry to strike down someone. [Sri Krishna forgave Shishupala's 1001 wrong actions before He used the Sudarshaana chakra to slay him].  In our and similar religions, it is ourKarma that results in good or bad befalling us.  Ane where the account does not balance - we are born with our Prarabda  Karma - the leftover of earlier life(s). In Abhramic religions - Judaism, Christianity, Islam, etc - Contd

Comment: Continued - In Abhramic religions - Judaism, Christianity, Islam, etc. there is no concept of reincarnation.  The deeds of a person is Known to God. On death a person's soul awaits the Day of Judgement - when the reward or punishment would be declared.

Answer (score 1):

In the legend where Lord Shiva stood as the flame of fire, Brahma, one of the Trimurthis thought that he could lie his way out by saying he found Lord Shiva's crown. Lord Shiva allowed him to fly first but later plucked his 5th head out. In Basmasura's case, Lord Shiva grants him the boon that anybody he lays his hand on will be burnt to death. Even to Ravana, Lord Shiva grants many boons. Lord Shiva is said to be a bestower of boons. But why? Where there is an effort, Lord Shiva being an embodiment of kindness, obliges. But, when the effort is for a wrong cause, Lord Shiva makes sure the arrogance of the native soars and he brings about his own ruin.

Comment: Lingodhbhava legend -- it is in Shiva Purana. Basmasura legend -- Vishnu purana. Ravana legend -- Quoted from several sites.